# changing datetime format from date to date time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a list of dates stored as strings. I need to convert them to this format `"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z"`

I can not achieve this since the date stored as a string has no time, just the date. eg. `2015-06-12`

below is one iteration of the code/idea i tried but failed. any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
d = "2015-06-12"

x = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d").date()    

x =  datetime.date(x) + datetime.time(10, 23)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace):

```
from datetime import datetime

d = "2015-06-12"
x = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d").replace(hour=10, minute=23)
```

To print it in desired format you can use [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
print(x.strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z"))
```

**BUT** it won't print timezone name (%Z), cause created `datetime` object has no information about timezone. You can add it manually, by providing time delta between UTC and timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

x = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d").replace(hour=10, minute=23,
                                             tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=6), name="CST"))
```

Or set local timezone:

```
x = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d").replace(hour=10, minute=23, 
                                             tzinfo=datetime.utcnow().astimezone().tzinfo)
```